# Excluding Condition From SUM Function SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, sql-server-2014

I am fairly new to SQL and I can not seem to figure a way to produce the results I am looking for. I am trying to get a SUM of all the A/R buckets by aging bucket and by facility. Within the buckets are a few different categories (Insurance, Lien & Pt. Responsibility) I want to include all categories in the SUM except "Lien". I keep getting the GROUP BY aggregate error. Can someone please assist? Thanks!

```
SELECT ar.[Report Date]
,ar.Facility
,(CASE WHEN ar.[Current Financial Class] <> 'Lien' THEN SUM (ar.[0-30]) END) AS [0-30]
,(CASE WHEN ar.[Current Financial Class] <> 'Lien' THEN SUM (ar.[31-60]) END) AS [31-60]
,(CASE WHEN ar.[Current Financial Class] <> 'Lien' THEN SUM (ar.[61-90]) END) AS [61-90]
,(CASE WHEN ar.[Current Financial Class] <> 'Lien' THEN SUM (ar.[91-120] + ar.[120+]) END) AS [91+]
FROM DBO.ARByPayer AS ar
GROUP BY ar.Facility, ar.[Report Date]
```

Comment: And what does the error say?

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Column 'DBO.ARByPayer.Current Financial Class' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply exclude those rows from your query with a where clause.

```
SELECT ar.[Report Date]
    , ar.Facility
    , SUM (ar.[0-30]) AS [0-30]
    , SUM (ar.[31-60]) AS [31-60]
    , SUM (ar.[61-90]) AS [61-90]
    , SUM (ar.[91-120] + ar.[120+]) AS [91+]
FROM DBO.ARByPayer AS ar
WHERE ar.[Current Financial Class] <> 'Lien'
GROUP BY ar.Facility
    , ar.[Report Date]
```

Comment: Thank you Sean! I should have known this. I completely forgot about the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with sub query.

```
Select [Report Date], Facility,  sum([0-30]) AS [0-30], sum([31-60]) AS [31-60], sum([61-90]) AS [61-90], sum([91+]) AS [91+]
        (SELECT ar.[Report Date]
        ,ar.Facility
        ,(CASE WHEN ar.[Current Financial Class] <> 'Lien' THEN ar.[0-30] END) AS [0-30]
        ,(CASE WHEN ar.[Current Financial Class] <> 'Lien' THEN ar.[31-60] END) AS [31-60]
        ,(CASE WHEN ar.[Current Financial Class] <> 'Lien' THEN ar.[61-90] END) AS [61-90]
        ,(CASE WHEN ar.[Current Financial Class] <> 'Lien' THEN ar.[91-120] + ar.[120+]) END) AS [91+]
        FROM DBO.ARByPayer AS ar) t
        GROUP BY Facility, [Report Date]
```